# How to get data from a third table?

Tags: php, yii, view, rating

My question is bit complex, I have tables name `business, Items, busines_items and item_review.`

```
Business has attributes business_id,business_name
Items has attributes item_id (pk), item_name,item_price,item_description
Business_Items has attributes business_items_id (pk), Business_id (fk),item_id, image
Item_review has attributes item_review_id (pk), business_items_id (fk), rating.
```

I want to show in a view of business, business_items_id from business_items table and rating of that item from item_review table.I have done some work, Through relationship i get the business_items_id. But How can i get the rating from item_review. so that when i go to this url `localhost/project/business/products/business_id` this view shows me all the products of that business along with their ratings and picture.

My view file in business/viewitems

```
<div class="container">

<div class="container">
<h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $model->business_name; ?>'s Products</h1>           <!-- add this heading in page-tittle -->

</div>
<?php $item=$model->businessItems;

?>

<div class="row row-wrap">
<?php foreach($item as $ba)
{
//                 echo $ba->id;

?>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumb">
<header class="thumb-header">
<a class="hover-img" href="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl?>/businessitems/itemspage/<?php echo $ba->id; ?>">
<img src="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl?>/img/<?php echo $ba->image;?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Items" />

</a>
</header>

<div class="thumb-caption">

<h5 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl?>/businessitems/itemspage/<?php echo $ba->id; ?>"><?php echo $ba->items->item_name; ?></a></h5>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php    } ?> 



</div>
</div>
<div class="gap gap-small"></div>
</div>
```

Model of business

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "business".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'business':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $business_name
 * @property string $image
 * @property string $business_description
 * @property string $opening_hours
 * @property string $closing_hours
 * @property string $days
 * @property string $Holiday
 * @property string $website
 * @property integer $phone
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Address[] $addresses
 * @property BusinessItems[] $businessItems
 * @property BusinessPackage[] $businessPackages
 *  * @property BusinessPhotos[] $businessPhotoses
 * @property ClaimBusiness[] $claimBusinesses
 * @property Facilities[] $facilities
 * @property ReviewBusiness[] $reviewBusinesses
 * @property SubCategoryBusiness[] $subCategoryBusinesses
 */
class Business extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'business';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('business_name, business_description, opening_hours, closing_hours, days', 'required'),
            array('phone', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('business_name', 'length', 'max'=>60),
            array('image, opening_hours, closing_hours, days, Holiday, website', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            array('business_description', 'length', 'max'=>500),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, business_name, image, business_description, opening_hours, closing_hours, days, Holiday, website, phone', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
         array('image', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'safe' => false,'on'=>'insert,update'),

                    );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'addresses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Address', 'business_id'),
            'businessItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BusinessItems', 'business_id'),
            'businessPackages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BusinessPackage', 'business_id'),
                        'businessPhotoses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BusinessPhotos', 'business_id'),
            'claimBusinesses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ClaimBusiness', 'business_id'),
            'facilities' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Facilities', 'business_id'),
            'reviewBusinesses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ReviewBusiness', 'business_id'),
            'subCategoryBusinesses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SubCategoryBusiness', 'business_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'business_name' => 'Business Name',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'business_description' => 'Business Description',
            'opening_hours' => 'Opening Hours',
            'closing_hours' => 'Closing Hours',
            'days' => 'Days',
            'Holiday' => 'Holiday',
            'website' => 'Website',
            'phone' => 'Phone',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('business_name',$this->business_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
        $criteria->compare('business_description',$this->business_description,true);
        $criteria->compare('opening_hours',$this->opening_hours,true);
        $criteria->compare('closing_hours',$this->closing_hours,true);
        $criteria->compare('days',$this->days,true);
        $criteria->compare('Holiday',$this->Holiday,true);
        $criteria->compare('website',$this->website,true);
        $criteria->compare('phone',$this->phone);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Business the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your Model, did you check the Yii Documentation about relations? You cann access then by $model->businessItems->item_review if you set up everything right in the Model

Comment: Dear, I want to access the data in my business view, not in my businessitems view. this is the main problem, and this is the actual question

Answer (score -1):

Any one who is interested in the answer here it goes.
My business controller is given below.

```
 public function actionViewitems($id)
 {
     //render main layout
     $this->layout = 'main';

     $rate = ItemReview::model()->findAll();
     $this->render('viewitems', array(
            'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
            'rate' => $rate, //pass data 
     ));
 }
```

Now I can access it by using `foreach` loop in my viewitems view.

```
foreach ($rate as $ba) {
    echo $ba->rating;
}
```

Now given below is my view file, where i am getting specific rating against specific business and specific business items.

```
        <div class="container">

            <div class="container">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $model->business_name; ?>'s Products</h1>           <!-- add this heading in page-tittle -->

        </div>
                        <?php 
function name($percentage){

if($percentage==0 && $percentage<0.5)
{ ?>     <div class="booking-item-rating">
      <ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
          <li><div class="rating_subcat">
   <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
   <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }   
elseif ($percentage>=0.5 && $percentage<1) { ?>   
  <div class="booking-item-rating">
      <ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
          <li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-half.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>

<?php }   
elseif ($percentage>=1 && $percentage<1.5) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }   
elseif ($percentage>=1.5 && $percentage<2) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-half.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;

</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php } 
elseif ($percentage>=2 && $percentage<2.5) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php } 
elseif ($percentage>=2.5 && $percentage<3) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-half.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }
elseif ($percentage>=3 && $percentage<3.5) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
 <div class="rating">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
                </div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }
elseif ($percentage>=3.5 && $percentage<4) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-half.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }
elseif ($percentage>=4 && $percentage<4.5) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">

                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-off.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }
elseif ($percentage>=4.5 && $percentage<5) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-half.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }
elseif ($percentage=5) { ?>    <div class="booking-item-rating"><ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars"><li><div class="rating_subcat">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo "star-on.png";?>">;
</div>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>
<?php }
}

     ?>
            <?php $item=$model->businessItems;

            ?>

            <div class="row row-wrap">
              <?php foreach($item as $ba)
              {
                   $bizitems=$ba->id;          //getting id of business items 
                   $biz=$ba->business_id;   //business id from model business items
                   $value=$model->id;                  //storing business id of current business
                   if($value==$biz){               //matching business id and business id from busienss items table
                     $image=$ba->image;            //geting image from business items table
                    $item_name=$ba->items->item_name; 
                    $sum=0; 
                    $time=0;
             ?>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumb">
                 <header class="thumb-header">
                <a class="hover-img" href="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl?>/businessitems/itemspage/<?php echo $bizitems; ?>">
                 <img src="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl?>/img/<?php echo $image;?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Items" />
                 </a>
                 </header>
                     <?php 

                     foreach ($rate as $ab){
                    $ratebiz=$ab->business_items_id;           //getting business items id from item review
                        if($ratebiz==$bizitems){                   //comparing business items id with business items id in item review
                             $sum=$sum+$ab->rating;
                          $time++;
                            }
                            }?>
                 <div class="thumb-caption">
                      <ul class="icon-group text-tiny text-color">
                         <?php  if($time!=0)
                                    {
                                    $percentage=$sum/$time;
                                      } ?>
                            <?php  name($percentage);//echo $percentage; //showing rating ?>
                    </ul>
       <h5 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php Yii::app()->request->baseUrl?>/businessitems/itemspage/<?php echo $ba->id; ?>"><?php echo $ba->items->item_name; ?></a></h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                   <?php   } } ?> 

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gap gap-small"></div>
        </div>
```